# Use VBA to query a directory and all subfolders in the directory and return the complete filepath in column A of a specific file extension

Tags: vba, excel

What I am looking to do is to list all files in a directory and its sub directory with a specific extension such as .pdb

And return those results to say Column A.

The following Code works but I am unsure of the syntax to use to only return a specific file extension type.

```
    Sub ListFiles()
Const sRoot     As String = "Y:\Engineering\Database Versions\Chillers"
Dim t As Date

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Columns("A:C")
    .ClearContents
    .Rows(1).Value = Split("File,Size,Date", ",")
End With

t = Timer
NoCursing sRoot
Columns.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub NoCursing(ByVal sPath As String)
Const iAttr     As Long = vbNormal + vbReadOnly + _
      vbHidden + vbSystem + _
      vbDirectory
Dim col         As Collection
Dim iRow        As Long
Dim jAttr       As Long
Dim sFile       As String
Dim sName       As String

If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

Set col = New Collection
col.Add sPath

iRow = 1

Do While col.count
    sPath = col(1)

    sFile = Dir(sPath, iAttr)

    Do While Len(sFile)
        sName = sPath & sFile

        On Error Resume Next
        jAttr = GetAttr(sName)
        If Err.Number Then
            Debug.Print sName
            Err.Clear

        Else
            If jAttr And vbDirectory Then
                If Right(sName, 1) <> "." Then col.Add sName & "\"
            Else
                iRow = iRow + 1
                If (iRow And &H3FF) = 0 Then Debug.Print iRow
                Rows(iRow).Range("A1:C1").Value = Array(sName, _
                                                        FileLen(sName), _
                                                        FileDateTime(sName))
            End If
        End If
        sFile = Dir()
    Loop
    col.Remove 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: There are tons of answers available on Google and on SO.

Comment: you are correct appologies. I have added an example that works for my use case except it is missing one piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **`Else...End If`** part with below code and it will only print files with **`.pdb`** extension.

```
'Your existing code
Else
    If InStr(1, sName, ".pdb", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        iRow = iRow + 1
        If (iRow And &H3FF) = 0 Then Debug.Print iRow
        Rows(iRow).Range("A1:C1").Value = Array(sName, _
                                                FileLen(sName), _
                                                FileDateTime(sName))
    End If
End If
'Your existing code
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help... :)

Comment: How difficult would it to be to add the following functionality to this.  To add another Header after Date and it Be Titled Containing Folder, then to return Just the Folder Name, not the full path, of the folder the file was located in?

Comment: Its not hard at all. Break your requirements and Google that, you will get plenty of answers my friend.